# Exercise about geometric progession

Tags: geometric-progressions

I have an statement that says:

> Find 3 numbers in P.G, if this numbers add up $12$ and its product is $-216$

I tried this:

[image]

The $r = \frac{\pm\sqrt{5} - 3}{2}$

And when i replace the $r$, it not give $12$ in the addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
r=\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
which gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
a=3(3 \pm \sqrt{5}) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
and so ($ar=-6$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+ar+ar^2 =3(3 \pm \sqrt{5})-6-3(-3 \pm \sqrt{5})=12 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
as required.

Comment: How you get $-3(-3 +|-\sqrt{5})$ to $3(3 +|- \sqrt{5})$

Comment: use $ar=-6$ and your formula for $r$ to simplify the third term.